# Kill attached screen session with numbers as session name

Tags: linux, centos, gnu-screen

I have this session for example `7540.27535      (Detached)`
and the `27535` is the session name, so it's not the id but the session name.

What I want is to kill the sessions with the name `27535`, How can I do that ?

I have multiple sessions with the same name but I also have another ones and I don't want to kill them all with killall screen.
The command I am using `screen -S 27535 -X quit` and the answer I get from the server is

```
No screen session found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
screen -ls | grep 27535  | cut -d. -f1 | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill
```